# PHP only taking the last row from MySQL DB in login form

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, authentication

I've been stuck on this issue for 3 days now. I'm trying to make a login form (I've already created a register form) and the database is working too. But now while I'm trying to make the login form, I've noticed that PHP only takes the last row from the database.

[image: 1]

As you can clearly see in the first picture, my database has 3 records.
But when I try to log in on my account, it only lets me log in to the most recently created account, and not the others. Here's my current code:

```
<div class="login-form">
    <form method="POST">
        <p style="float:left;">
            <input type="email" class="login-input" maxlength="40" name="login-email" id="login-email" placeholder="email" required><span style="color: red;">&nbsp;*</span><br><br>
             <input type="password" class="login-input" maxlength="32" name="login-passw" id="login-passw" placeholder="password" required><span style="color: red;">&nbsp;*</span><br><br>
             <input type="submit" class="btn" name="login-btn">
         </p>
         <?php
         $email = $_POST["login-email"];
         $passw = $_POST["login-passw"];
         $encrypted_passw = md5($passw);

         $sql = "SELECT id, email, passw FROM users";
         $result = $db->query($sql);

         // if (isset($_POST["login-btn"])) {
         //     if ($_POST["login-email"] == $result["email"]) {
         //         echo "<p>Logged in</p>";
         //     } else {
         //         echo "<p>wrong</p>";
         //     }
         // }
         while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             $get_email = $row["email"];
             $get_usr = $row["username"];
             $get_passw = $row["passw"];
         }

         if (isset($_POST["login-btn"])) {
             if ($_POST["login-email"] == $get_email && $encrypted_passw == $get_passw) {
                 echo "<p>Logged in</p>";
             } else {
                 echo "<p> wrong</p>";
             }
        }
        ?>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I know you're excited, but please try to keep your language under control. Think of Stack Overflow as more like Wikipedia than like Reddit.

Comment: Change your logic to do a lookup on the email address.  ‘Where email=provided-email’. Then check the supplied password and email match. You are currently iterating through each row and overwriting get_email each time hence why when you do the comparison it’s comparing the last result

Comment: Please please [please read this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) about password hashing. md5-hashed passwords are almost as easy to hack as unhashed passwords.

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes created using PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which you can then verify using [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Take a look at this post: [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/1839439) and learn more about [bcrypt & password hashing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1839439)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.  First of all I would place the php code above the HTML.

You only need to listen the post param `login-btn`. Read the other post data into vars and confirm its there before proceeding.

When you poll the DB you dont need to read every record (imagine you have thousands of records, you wouldn't want to pull them all down). Just filter for the supplied email with a where clause.

If the email exists it will return a result with the hashed password. Verify this matches and you are good to go.

The issue you're having where the last record in the db is beiung used is becuase in your loop, you are overwriting the var                 `$get_email` each time.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["login-btn"])) {

    $email = (isset($_POST["login-email"]) ? $_POST["login-email"] : '');
    $passw = (isset($_POST["login-passw"]) ? $_POST["login-passw"] : '');

    if($email != "" && $passw != ""){

        $encrypted_passw = md5($passw);    

        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT email, passw FROM users where email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param($email);
        $stmt->execute();

        while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {

            $get_passw = $row["passw"];

            if($encrypted_passw == $row['passw']){
                echo "logged in";
            }else{
                echo 'no match';
            }
        }
    }
}    
?>

<div class="login-form">
    <form method="POST">
        <p style="float:left;">
            <input type="email" class="login-input" maxlength="40" name="login-email" id="login-email" placeholder="email" required><span style="color: red;">&nbsp;*</span><br><br>
            <input type="password" class="login-input" maxlength="32" name="login-passw" id="login-passw" placeholder="password" required><span style="color: red;">&nbsp;*</span><br><br>
            <input type="submit" class="btn" name="login-btn">
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Now it doesn't even echo the result

Comment: want to help with some useful debugging information? Are there any php errors, check the logs etc.

Comment: @NikkieDev there was a syntax error with the isset tenary calls. I have updated the code. You should enable errors while developing/learning

Answer (score -2):

change your query to this

> "SELECT id, email, passw FROM users where email='".$row["email"]."'
> and password= '".$row["password"]."'"

you do not need to use foreach for all rows this query return only one row that you need

Comment: this was expose the application to SQL injection. '; TRUNCATE users; --